# Displaying Multiple Images using labelProvider

Tags: eclipse-plugin

We have been working in a Tree Editor. We are displaying icons below the file names. Now, we have a need to display another icons below this already displayed icon. This icon will be displayed based on some parameters. Hence, it is not necessary that always multiple icons will be displayed.

We have our own LabelProvider which correctly returns a single image.

Please, let me know how can I customise my LabelProvider to return multiple images ?

Answer (score 1):

The normal `LabelProvider` only supports returning a single image per row.

There are some classes available which let you make a composite image from several separate images. The abstract base class for these is `CompositeImageDescriptor`. The `DecorationOverlayIcon` class is a concrete class based in this which supports a main image with up to four overlay images (this is what views like Package Explorer use).

If those classes are not enough you can use a label provider based on `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` - which allows you to draw what you like in the row.

Note: All rows in a tree (or table) are always the same height. A deep image in one row will force all the other rows to be the same depth.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'll have a try